# Forward mail from Exchange to external host in addition to local delivery

Tags: exchange-2010

as part of a migration scenario we need to be able to receive mails on our local Exchange 2010 SP1 server as well as forward all incoming mail to an external host (even if mail is succesfully delivered on local server). Is there a way to do this in Exchange 2010 or do I need to set up another SMTP server in front which can send incoming emails to two different hosts?

regards, 
Trond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676395.aspx

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, this config will only forward mail that is not resolved locally :-(. I need it to forward regardless.

Comment: We ended up scripting a forwarder contact for each user and went with the shared address space option. Thank god for PowerShell :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can journal all the inbound emails to another account.  We use this for echoing all emails back to postini for archiving.  I don't know if this will work for you as it will echo everything and its done at the database level.

Check this out:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998649.aspx